# Using sine rule to determine periodic functions

Tags: trigonometry, wave-equation

I have the question "Determine by calculation, the periodic functions in the form $v = v_m\sin(wt \pm a)$ for

$$80\sin(wt + \pi/3) + 50\sin(wt - \pi/6)"$$

Here is my attempt:

[image]

For the cosine rule part I get the correct maximum voltage(Vm) of 94.34 V.

However, when I use the sine rule to work out the phase angle I get 0.559 radians and the solutions say that it should be 0.489 radians, so where have I gone wrong ?

Comment: See the first entry in table 2 [here](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/635.php) for formula that works.